# just need to put the 1 image on the top and the second image would be on the bottom part

Tags: html, css

I just need to put the 1 image on the top and the second image would be on the bottom part of the background is that possible?  please help me on this many thanks

```
html { background:url(../images/try.jpg) repeat-y top center; width:100%; height:100%;}

body {
    font: 100% Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background:url(../images/try2.jpg) no-repeat bottom center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center; 
    color: #000000;
    height:100%;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS 3 ....

```
body {
    font: 100% Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: url(../images/try2.jpg) no-repeat bottom center,
                url(../images/try2.jpg) no-repeat bottom center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center; 
    color: #000000;
    height:100%;

}
```

But to make it cross browser, above is the the solution by treefrog ;)